# How to register javascript file while opening aspx via hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have hyperlinks on an aspx page.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlTasks" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ChildrensIPOutcome.aspx?EntityTypeId={0}&EntityId={1}&EntityTypeName={2}&LoadFromActionResult=True&ParentEntityId={4}",Eval("EntityTypeId"), Eval("EntityId"),"Participants.Parents",Eval("EntityOfficialName"),Request.QueryString("EntityId"))%>' runat="server"><%# Eval("EntityOfficialName") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

The page ChildrensIPOutcome.aspx needs to register a Jscript file. How do I do that?

Comment: i assume this is an AJAX call? otherwise loading a script file on load probably wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The page opened (ChildrensIPOutcome.aspx) must register/run the JavaScript itself. Put the appropriate script controls or tags (in ChildrensIPOutcome.aspx) as required.

Comment: I have to register the script like this:    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "key" & count & currentControl.ClientID, "<script type=""text/javascript""> $(document).ready(function () { $(""#" & currentControl.ClientID & """).mask(""999-999-9999"");});</script>", False). This is because it is adding 'asmking' to the user controls which are generated dynamically

Comment: correction- Not 'asmking'. Its 'Masking'